# Docker daemon not starting without error

Tags: linux, docker, daemon, suse, sles

With a new installation of docker (v17.04.0-ce), I have a quite strange error :

After starting the daemon with `$sudo service docker start` (or the systemctl command, it leads to the same), I've got a

`Job for docker.service failed. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xn" for details.`

Ok. But here is the systemctl log (without useless stuff) :

No worries for the warning message "DON'T BIND etc".

```
docker_service_helper.sh[6072]: Waiting for docker daemon to start
dockerd[6071]: time="2017-07-25T16:52:44Z" level=info msg="SUSE:secrets :: enabled"
dockerd[6071]: time="2017-07-25T16:52:44.586908486Z" level=warning msg="[!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU D...E DOING [!]"
dockerd[6071]: time="2017-07-25T16:52:44.589514048Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: btrfs"
dockerd[6071]: time="2017-07-25T16:54:14.752334096Z" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
```

So it gets terminated, but no trace of timeout !
Unfortunately, the journalctl isn't more verbose.

My OS is : SLES 12 sp1 (offline system)

Running `dockerd -D` leads to a `docker-containerd` not found in the PATH, but I've got another server with this issue as well, and on which the docker daemon is running ...

If someone knows how to fix this, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that was incredibly tricky.
To solve this, rename `/var/lib/docker` in something else (for backup, who knows ...), create a new `/var/lib/docker` directory, and ... it should start !

Comment: That usually happens when your docker setup gets corrupted. Doesn't happen very often but I have experienced this twice with older version of docker