# starting docker daemon times out in openSUSE 15.0

Tags: opensuse, docker

I installed docker 17.09.1 on openSUSE Leap 15.0 via zypper. Unfortunately starting the docker service always times out.

output of `systemctl start docker`:

```
Job for docker.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl  status docker.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

output of `journalctl`:

```
Oct 28 10:38:06 linux-j8zs dockerd[3786]: time="2018-10-28T10:38:06.692915975+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Oct 28 10:38:06 linux-j8zs dockerd[3786]: time="2018-10-28T10:38:06.693258146+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Oct 28 10:39:36 linux-j8zs systemd[1]: docker.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 28 10:39:36 linux-j8zs dockerd[3786]: time="2018-10-28T10:39:36.730854796+01:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Oct 28 10:41:06 linux-j8zs systemd[1]: docker.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Oct 28 10:41:06 linux-j8zs systemd[1]: docker.service: Killing process 3786 (dockerd) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 10:41:06 linux-j8zs systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Oct 28 10:41:06 linux-j8zs systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 28 10:41:06 linux-j8zs systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 28 10:41:06 linux-j8zs systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

What I tried:

1. Emptying `/var/lib/docker` like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381731/docker-daemon-not-starting-without-error)
2. Adding the user to the group docker and reboot like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382262/cannot-start-docker-daemon-in-opensuse)
3. Starting the daemon via `systemctl start docker --` like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382262/cannot-start-docker-daemon-in-opensuse)

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

@Marph,

Journal logs clearly shows your kernel not supporting cgroup feature.

```
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
```

Try to update your kernel version and take a reboot.
Once server back online your docker service will be up and running.

Regards,
Babin [linuxsysadmins.com](https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/)

Comment: I tried to update my kernel, but it can't load the `bbswitch` module. I will post if I can get it working.